# In iOS an application with a demo-video file(huge size) added to it, can impact RAM?

Tags: swift, core-data, memory-management, ios8

I am new to app development and actually, I had recorded a demo video of the application and I had attached it to the application project

- So now my application has increased to 38mb from 8mb { code size=8mb, video size = 30 mb}
- So my question is when the application is running, whether the entire application 38mb will sit on the RAM or while playing the demo video alone the 30mb-video will sit on the RAM ??
- And what's the maximum size that Apple allows for an application in iOS?

Here is my code that shows how I play a video using Media player:

```
    var moviePlayer : MPMoviePlayerController?
    @IBOutlet weak var playerView: UIView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        playVideo()
    }

    func playVideo() {
        
        let videoPath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("pjt", ofType:"mov")
        
        //Make a URL from your path
        let url = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(videoPath!)
        
        //Initalize the movie player
        moviePlayer = MPMoviePlayerController(contentURL: url)
        
        if let player = moviePlayer {
           
            player.view.frame = self.playerView.frame
            player.scalingMode = .AspectFit
            self.view.addSubview(player.view)
        
            //Play the video
            player.prepareToPlay()
            
        }
        else {
            println("Movie player failed")
        }
    }
```

Comment: Xcode can show you how much memory your app is using, while the app is running.